# JodaTime: plusMonths(1) two times differ from plusMonths(2)

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime

Sample test

```
@Test
public void should_be_equals(){
    LocalDate now = new LocalDate(2015,01,29);
    assertThat(now.plusMonths(1).plusMonths(1)).isEqualTo(now.plusMonths(2));
}
```

The strange result:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :2015-03-29
Actual   :2015-03-28
```

Why this differs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you would add one month to `2015/01/29`, you would get `2015/02/29` - since 2015 isn't a leap year, that's not a valid date, so Joda chooses `2015/02/28`, [as documented](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-int-):

> The addition may change the year, but the day-of-month is normally
>   unchanged. If adding months makes the day-of-month invalid, it is
>   adjusted to the last valid day in the month.

And another month added to `2015/02/28` will result in the actual date `2015/03/28`.

The problem with the missing 29th of February doesn't appear when adding two months, because Joda never gets an invalid date.

The same does apply to, for instance, `new LocalDate(2015, 03, 31).plusMonths(2)` versus `new LocalDate(2015, 03, 31).plusMonths(1).plusMonths(1)` - I guess, this is more common than leap years.